# Bootstrap: Collapse does not work right after using Collapse Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Please refer to: http://jsfiddle.net/72nfxgjs/

The code is picked up from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_collapse&stacked=h

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $("#collapse1").collapse('hide');
   $("#collapse2").collapse('show');
   </script>
```

Once the above code is added to the page, to manually hide the first panel and show the next, the first two panels stop hiding other panels when the show.

How can this be solved?

Update:
By Default I do not want the first panel to be hidden and the second visible, I want to perform that operation on button click(Or any other javascript code).
Also by onclick adding and removing class removes the animation does not cause icon change event(http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_collapse_togglebtn&stacked=h)

Comment: why are you using this additional collapse code. you dont need it. manually it will work exactly as it has to do

Comment: @MeeneshJain Hey! Question Updated :D Sorry for less information :) The Application has been mentioned now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding own script is somewhat disturbing the manner bootstrap accordion behaves. To achieve the above result, you do not need script, you can do this by using the classes `.collapse`: hides the content and `.collapse.in`: shows the content.

So make the following changes in your HTML:

```
 <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

to

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

and

```
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

to

```
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

to achieve the same. See the fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/72nfxgjs/1/"

Comment: Actually by default I do not want it to hide the first panel and show the first, but onclick I want that behavior to occur.

Comment: Then using onclick you can add or remove class

Comment: Please refer to updated question, That affects the animation + the icon update.